# Load customized Dojo module

Tags: module, dojo, require

I am really new to Dojo so this may sound dumb.

I am using Dojo 1.7 as a hosted resource (that is, I downloaded the dojo package and put it under the source code). Then I have a customized module defined in another folder. The structure looks like this:

```
/
  libs/
    js/
      dojo/
        dojo.js
  myPage/
    myModules/
      myCustomizedModule.js
    index.html
```

I am using the "define" function to define a module in myPage/myModules/myCustomizedModule.js

In "myPage" folder, I am using index.html to require the customized module:

```
<script>
   require(["myPage/myModules/myCustomizedModule"], function(myCustomizedModule){
     // Do something.
   })
</script>
```

However, I can't get it to work: the console reported an error:
"http://localhost/myDojoTest/libs/js/dojo/myPage/MyModules/myCustomizedModule.js 404 (Not found)".

I know this directory is not right since "myPage" folder is not under "libs/js/dojo". But it seems when using the "require" statement, instead of using the relative path of the current HTML document, the code uses the current path for the dojo.js file.

Is there anything I can do to correctly refer to my customized module?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your requirement, you need to set up packages as indicated below

```
<!-- dojo configuration options -->
<!-- For Package configuration refer tutorial at     http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.7/modules/ -->
<script type="text/javascript">
        var dojoConfig = {
            async: true,
            baseUrl: "/",
            tlmSiblingOfDojo: false,
            packages: [
                { name: "dojo",  location: "libs/js/dojo" },
                { name: "dijit", location: "libs/js/dijit" },
                { name: "dojox", location: "libs/js/dojox" },
                { name: "myModules", location: "myPage/myModules" }
            ]
        };
    </script>
```

You can than access dojo, dijit and myModules in `require` function call as.

**Remember** you need to **precede** the modules with their respective packages.

```
<script>
        require([
            //Require resources.
            "dojo/store/Memory",
            "myModules/myCustomizedModule"
        ], function(Memory, myCustomizedModule){
           ....
        }
        );
</script>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes! I just figure it out by doing researches! Same answer as yours :) Thank you!

Comment: @Eric if you find the answer useful, please consider accept it or up-voting :)